# Spring effect with TweenJS

Tags: javascript, animation, tween, tween.js

What would be the TweenJS parameter to create a tween scale effect similar to the 'spring' transformation in Adobe Flash like this:

[image: Spring effect]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it's the 'elasticOut' one.

```
mc.scaleX = 0.01;
mc.scaleY = 0.01;
createjs.Tween.get(mc).to({scaleX:1, scaleY:1}, 1500, createjs.Ease.elasticOut);

createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```